# Yu yureka Recovery

Tags: micromax-yu-yureka

I have yu yureka phone on which I tried to unlock the bootloader and flash cwm recovery. As the process continued and at last the window showed ' finished'. I then tried to boot into recovery mode by pressing all hardware keys simultaneously but it didn't opened recovery and the phone started to homescreen. I need to know whether recovery is installed properly or not. I don't want to boot into the recovery mode because last time it did so and the phone was in bootloop so is there any way to know if the recovery is installed properly or not without rebooting it in recovery mode. 
Thanks. Please help.